# How to prove that a function $f\colon c_0\to c_0$ is not Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions

I wonder if the following function $f\colon c_0\to c_0$ ( $c_0$ is a space of real sequences convergent to 0 with supremum norm)
$$ f(x)=(f_{n}(x)),$$
where $f_n(x)=\sqrt{|x_n|}+\frac{1}{n+1}$
is Lipschitz? I want to prove that it isn't. So, I pick $x,y\in c_0$ and consider
$$\|f(x)-f(y)\|=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|\sqrt{|x_n|}-\sqrt{|y_n|}|.$$
At first I thought that it is enough to ask whether $g(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ is Lipschitz continuous, but on the other hand there is the supremum. Maybe there are sequences $(x_{n}), (y_n)$ such that Lipschitz codition does not hold?

Comment: I guess you mean $f(\mathbf{x})_n=f_n(x_n)$?

Comment: I mean, for $x\in c_0$, $f(x)=y$, where $y\in c_0$ and $y=(y_n)$, $y_n=\sqrt{|x_n|}+\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Yes, that  is what I said.

Comment: Anyway, if $x_n=y_n$ for all $n \neq k$, then $\| f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{y}) \| =|\sqrt{x_k}-\sqrt{y_k}|$, and now you've reduced to the one dimensional case.

Comment: ok, and the square root is not a Lipschitz function, at least if I recall corectly (on $[0,1]$). Could you explain, what do you mean by $x_n=y_n$ if $n\ne k$?

Comment: I just meant that you can restrict attention to sequences which only differ in one position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be enough. Because you can take the the subset $c_0' \subset c_0$ defined by
$$c_0' := \{ (x_n)_n \ | \ x_k = 0 \text{ for } k \geq 2\}$$ 
Then take $x,y \in c_0'$ so that
$$f(x) - f(y) = (\sqrt{|x_n|} - \sqrt{|y_n|})_n = (\sqrt{|x_1|} - \sqrt{|y_1|}, 0,0,...)$$
Let $g(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$, then 
$$|g(x_1) - g(y_1)| = ||f(x) - f(y)|| = \big|\sqrt{|x_1|} - \sqrt{|y_1|}\big|$$
Which is not Lipschitz.

Comment: as @ Ian mentioned, you can take the kth element instead of the first.

Comment: Exactly, thank you!